# Quickblox and Pro Guard error

Tags: android, proguard, quickblox

I'm developing an app that uses the Quickblox SDK. If I compile it with

```
minifyEnabled false
```

It work's fine. But if I enable minify to obfuscate the code I get the following error:

```
09-15 15:00:50.865  12029-12029/com.app.meet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.meet, PID: 12029
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.g.b.d.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.meet.App.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.meet.j.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.meet.h.e.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1208)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1225)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.smack.initializer.VmArgInitializer
        at c.b.a.q.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

I noticed that the org.jivesoftware.smack package is inside quickblox-android-sdk-chat-2.3.1.jar

By reading some answers in the site I modified my proguard-rules.pro like this:

```
#QuickBlox
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.initializer.VmArgInitializer { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.module.c.a.c { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.module.chat.QBChatService { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.module.chat.QBChatService.loginWithUser { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.module.chat.listeners.SessionCallback { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smackx.** { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class * implements org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.SmackDebugger { public *; }
```

I hope someone has an idea of what might be the problem here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the proguard rules that got it working. Hope it helps someone.

```
-dontwarn org.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

# Remove Logging statements
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.antew.redditinpictures.library.imgur.** { *; }
-keep class com.antew.redditinpictures.library.reddit.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

#QuickBlox
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smackx.** { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class * implements org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.SmackDebugger { public *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is not working with me case quickblox video calling , app crashing again and again then i tried another pro guard rules that working.

Go to proguard-rules.pro(app) file in app and copy and paste below all lines. its working

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working 
with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.quickblox.core.account.model.** { *; }

#quickblox sample chat
-keep class com.quickblox.auth.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.auth.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.server.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.rest.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.error.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.Query { *; }

-keep class com.quickblox.users.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.users.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.quickblox.chat.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.chat.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.quickblox.messages.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.messages.model.** { *; }

-keep class com.quickblox.content.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.content.model.** { *; }

-keep class org.jivesoftware.** { *; }

 #sample chat
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class com.bumptech.** { *; }

-dontwarn org.jivesoftware.smackx.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.app.**
```