# Quickblox-2.4 with Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am trying to integrate Proguard with Quickblox-2.4 jars. My logcat is showing this exception:

```
: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.d.a.b.v cannot be cast to com.quickblox.users.model.QBUserWrap
:   at com.quickblox.users.model.QBUserPaged.getEntity(QBUserPaged.java:32)
:   at com.quickblox.users.model.QBUserPaged.getEntity(QBUserPaged.java:13)
:   at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBJsonParser.b(QBJsonParser.java:123)
:   at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBJsonParser.parse(QBJsonParser.java:81)
:   at com.quickblox.core.query.Query$VersionEntityCallback.completedWithResponse(Query.java:334)
:   at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:260)
:   at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:41)
:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my proguard config file content for Quickblox:

```
#QuickBlox
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smackx.** { public *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class * implements org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.SmackDebugger { public *; }
```

I think may be this code is giving error, but I'm not sure. Please help! Thanks in advance.

```
QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(1000);
    QBUsers.getUsers(pagedRequestBuilder,
            new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> qbUsers,
                        Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                    // DialogUtils.showLong(ctx, errors.get(0));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594915/quickblox-and-pro-guard-error

Comment: Hi, I also tried using that proguard config file, but it's not working at my end. I am unable to figure out the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to reply, was facing the same issue and find some proguard rules and the issue is resolved now, may it will help someone too.

**Proguard rules for QuickBlox :**

```
-keep class com.quickblox.auth.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.auth.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.server.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.rest.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.error.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.core.Query { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.users.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.users.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.chat.parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.chat.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.messages.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.messages.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.content.parsers.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.content.model.** { *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jivesoftware.smackx.**
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smack.** { public *; }
-keep class org.jivesoftware.smackx.** { *; }
-keep class com.quickblox.** { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smack { public *; }
-keep class * extends org.jivesoftware.smackx
-keep class * implements org.jivesoftware.smack.debugger.SmackDebugger { public *; }
```